# How to copy vector graphics from Illustrator to Photoshop as shape layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I do lot of work in vectors. How can I copy an Illustrator-created shape with stroke into Photoshop as shape layer with the same stroke and everything I used in illustrator? Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot copy Illustrator settings like stroke into Photoshop unless you place it as a smart object preserving everything. You can still apply layer styles to the smart object and edit the content in Illustrator. Which should cover most of your use-cases. You just wont have a shape layer.  So your choices are **shape or smart object**.

Comment: and you can do that just by copy & pasting objects from illustrator to photoshop. Photoshop will ask how you want to place it. You can also use the `File > Place...` features in photoshop to place an `.ai` file to the document. Each time you start to edit the contents of that smart object, the file will open in illustrator, where you can edit the contents.

Comment: The smart objet could'nt have quality issues when you enlarge it. It comes from illustrator and he keep his vector property.